# Shopify: If cart has one item and price is below 10, set quantity of item to 0. Can't quite get it

Tags: javascript, shopify

Currently have a modal cart pop-up in my store. When a user adds an item to their cart, they are presented with the option to add a "Special Bundle" upsell which is a discounted item below $10. Unfortunately, some people are removing the original item, and checking out only the discounted upsell. My goal is that if an item is removed from the cart, a check is made to determine if there is only a single item in the cart, and if the value of that single item is under $10, to then set its quantity to 0, which will remove it from the cart.

```js
 ==============================================================================*/
  function ajaxSubmitCart() {
    $cart = $("#cart");
    $.ajax({
      url: '/cart.js',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'post',
      data: $cart.serialize(),
      success: function (data) {
        refreshCart(data);
        //updateCartIconNumber(data);
      }
    });
  }
  
  function refreshCart(cart) {

    $cartBtn = $(".icon-cart");
    if ($cartBtn) {
      var $cartCount = $cartBtn.find('.cart_count');
      var value = $cartCount.text() || '0';
      var cart_items_html = "";
      var newCart = $("#cart ul").empty();
      var $cart = $("#cart ul");     
      var cartNumber = 0;
      var product_ids = [];
      
      $cart.find('li:not(:first)').remove();

        
      
      if (cart.item_count == 0) {
        
        // This removes the upsell item OPT-IN / Call To Action if the cart has no cart items. The problem is removing the upsell item after a customer has added it to the cart, and they then remove the full priced item.
        
        $("#hero-offer").fadeOut(0,function() { $("#hero-offer").remove(); });
        $cart.append('<li class="mm-label empty_cart"><img class="empty-cart-image" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1442/0084/t/7/assets/Cart-Empty-TF2.png"><div class="cart-empty-text"></div></li>');
      
      } else {       
      
      // Believe I need another if statement here that checks qty to determine if there is only one item in cart, and then checks if its price is less than $10, and if yes, sets its item qty to 0, which effectively removes the upsell item that is on its own
      
        $.each(cart.items, function(index, item) {
          cart_items_html += '<li class="cart_item">' +
            '<a href="' + item.url +'">';
          if (item.image) {
            cart_items_html += '<div class="cart_image">' +
                '<img src="' + item.image.replace(/(\.[^.]*)$/, "_medium$1").replace('http:', '') + '" alt="' + htmlEncode(item.title) + '" />' +
              '</div>';
          }
          cart_items_html += '<div class="item_title">' + item.title +'</div></a>' +
              '<div class="price"> ' + Shopify.formatMoney(item.price, $cart.data('money-format')) + '</div>' +
              '<div class="quantity_selector">' +
                '<span class="minus">-</span><input type="number" min="0" class="quantity" name="updates[]" id="updates_' + item.id + '" value="' + item.quantity + '" /><span class="plus">+</span>' +
              '</div>' +            
          '</li>';
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that what you propose is the most appropriate solution. What if a customer has a genuine single (not upsell) item they want to buy. Perhaps it would be better to flag the upsell item as a 'bundle-item' somehow in the cart. Then your cart logic could remove such an item if it's the only item in the cart, rather than having to evaluate it based on price.

Comment: @Moob The reason I targeted price is because no items in my store outside of upsell items will ever be below $10. This way the bundle names can changed.

Comment: 100% of your problem here is relying on javascript to alter/update the cart. No matter what you do, anyone can use same Javascript to order whatever they want, breaking your rules, and checking out with goods where you lose. Trying to do your own upsells this way is risky.

Comment: @DavidLazar Unfortunately I use an upsell cart app, and they don't have include the option to have the added upsell item automatically remove if it is the only item in the cart. Customers will not go out of their way to get around the javascript, especially as it would be clear that they are meddling with the system and that their order would likely not be fulfilled. I'm okay with any that go out of their way to bypass it as it would probably be so seldom it would be negligible.

Comment: good luck to you then!